# "randint" function working unexpectedly inside functions?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, random

I need to use the `random.randint` inside of a function, but it always returns weird results. However, when I try it outside of the function, it works perfectly.

Here's a quick function to choose a number between one and six to illustrate my point:

```
import random

def dice():
    return random.randint(1, 7)

print(dice)
```

And then I get an output like:

```
<function dice at 0x0000000004314D90>
```

I would really appreciate it if you could explain what's happening and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the `dice` function and then print the result (return value).

```
print(dice())
#         ^^
```

In Python, functions are called by placing `(...)` after their names.  If your function takes any arguments, they would go where the `...` is and be separated by commas:

```
func(arg1, arg2)
```

Your current code was printing `<function dice at 0x0000000004314D90>` because that is the representation of the function object that you were printing.

Comment: Oh man, I feel so stupid... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you are simply forgetting a set of parenthesis. it should be

`print(dice())`

now you are printing the function object.

Comment: Oh man, I feel so stupid... Thanks a lot.